# how to browse an image and store that image in the database using LINQ to SQL in ASP.NET and how to retrieve that image?

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq

how to browse an image using a browse button and store that image as an image type in the database using LINQ to SQL in ASP.NET and as same as how to retrieve that image from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many articles on doing exactly this. Here are some links:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/LivMic/using-linq-when-working-with-images-in-web-application/

http://debugmode.net/2010/05/10/inserting-and-retrieving-image-using-linq-to-sql-from-asp-net-application/

Comment: thanx Wizurd,,,I'll follow those articles.